# Select the li in the list

Tags: html, css

List:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1-1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-1</a></li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#">Item 1-1-2</a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-2-1</li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here's some relevant CSS

```
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The first one will hide every drop down item. The second will match any ul that is a children of the parent #nav ul li:hover, if so display:block and the drop down is visible.

Now because when hovering a item, the items within will simply be listed below, this is not what I am looking to achieve. I want to move the Item 1-1-1 and Item 1-1-2 to be on the right of Item 1-1, the Item 1-1-1 needs to be on the right, Item 1-1-2 will be below it (acting as a drop-down list). I am not sure how I select that element. 
 Example: http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html

Here's what I got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8C2/

I tried with first-child, such as:

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

I also tried using position absolute and relative, It almost gave me the result I wanted, but I wasn't able to grab the first item...

There must be a better way of doing this...

How do I select it? And how do I make a similar behavior to that I've been describing above?

Comment: "The first one..." -- The first one of what set? I don't know what you are reffering to.

Comment: The #nav ul ul { display: none; } will hide any nested ul.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8C2/7/ some like this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the css/html of the page you linked to instead of trying to reinvent it?

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[CSS](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/style.css)

Answer (score 0):

Review this Fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8C2/10/**

I use `position:absolute` for the sub-sub menu :

```
#nav ul li ul li ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
}
```

In order to upgrade your code you can assign a class for each level of the menu like

```
<ul class="Third_level">
```